# ASP.NET MVC 3 get radiobutton value and masking field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I have this RadioButton:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Person.Type)
    @Html.Label("Type1")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Person.Type, "F", new { disabled = "disabled" })


    @Html.Label("Type2")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Person.Type, "J", new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

And, I have this Display:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Person.Field)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Person.Field)
```

I need a javascript function that replace this Dispay (Person.Field) if RadioButton is checked at "Type1" ("F").
How can I do this?

Comment: and [What have YOU tried ?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: At my Input screen I used masked input javascript.    I tried  $(function () {
        // bind the change function as usual
        $(':radio[name=Person.Type]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'F') {
                alert("F");
            } else {
                alert("J");
            }
        }).change();  // and immediately trigger it
    });  But shows like 2 alerts of "F" and 2 alerts of "J"

Comment: what HTML markup ir produces. Post that pls

Comment: <label for="Person_Type">Type Person</label>

            <label for="Type1">Type1</label>

            <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="Person_Type" name="Person.Type" type="radio" value="F" />





            <label for="Type2">Type2</label>

            <input disabled="disabled" id="Person_Type" name="Person.Type" type="radio" value="J" />